# Is there a common Android option that keeps call logs as long as there is space on the phone?

Tags: call-history

I think the question says it all. I was wondering if I can make my android phone never delete call logs. That's it.

Comment: If your device is rooted and you have the Xposed framework installed, you could e.g. use the [Unlimited Calllog](https://repo.xposed.info/module/pl.qbanin.xposed.unlimitedcalllog) module to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly it really depends greatly on the phone OS (i.e. skin) on whether you will have certain options. As far as I know, there is none, although I rarely have problems with call logs being gone. I suggest one of the multitude of call log apps that will back up said calls regularly.